# Change Tracking SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS on Update operation

Tags: sql-server, replication, t-sql, change-tracking

I would like to get an understanding of why on an update operation in the change tracking table, the SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS can be NULL. I would expect the SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS will be populated.
In the example below, the first and second record's update has a NULL value on SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS but the first record's SYS_CHANGE_VERSION <> SYS_CHANGE_CREATION_VERSION.
The third record contains a value in the SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS but the SYS_CHANGE_CREATION_VERSION is NULL.
We use SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS as a filter for updates to check if it is populated and it looks like we may be missing updates in this case. Any feedback on this is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48635050/5059085):

> SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS is null when every column is "updated". "Updated" here doesn't nessarily mean the value changed, it just means the column was touched by the DML statement. So, "update t set c = c" would mean column c was "updated".

I interpret it to mean that it records that an `UPDATE` statement took place, but nothing actually changed, such as the above example where column `c` is just being set to itself, without change.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/changetable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#changetable-changes) calls this out specifically:

> The value is `NULL` when any one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - Column change tracking is not enabled.
> - The operation is an insert or delete operation.
> - All nonprimary key columns were updated in one operation.

The final one is probably the relevant one.